# Passing an event to a parent component with Nuxt.js

Tags: vuejs2, click, vue-component, nuxt.js, vue-props

I have a simple header component which contains a clickable hamburger, I want to separate the hamburger into a separate component, but the click event no longer works when I do so, I think I need some kind of boolean prop but can't find an explanation or I'm looking for the wrong thing.

This works as a single component

/components/Header.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="--row header__wrapper" :class="{active: menuClose}">
    <button class="hamburger" :class="{active: menuClose}" @click="menuClose=!menuClose">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      menuClose: false,
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

The below doesn't work as loses click event when separated into two components which is where I am stuck.

/components/Header.vue

```
<template>
<div class="--row header__wrapper" :class="{active: menuClose}">
        <Hamburger/>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Hamburger from "~/components/Hamburger.vue";
  export default {
    components: {
      Hamburger
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

/components/Hamburger.vue

```
<template>
  <button class="hamburger" :class="{active: menuClose}" @click="menuClose=!menuClose">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      menuClose: false
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Send event from Child to parent component and make the menuClose via prop in child.
It is very easy to implement, follow

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events

Nuxt has nothing to do with events.

**EDIT**
I have created an example for you

https://codesandbox.io/embed/codesandbox-nuxt-v5l5m?fontsize=14

Comment: Thanks for the response I have read the docs and tried the following with no joy so far but still plucking away at it. /components/Header.vue `<template>
  <div
    class="--row header__wrapper"
    :class="{active: menuClose}"
    v-on:menuClick="menuClose=!menuClose"
  >
    <header class="--row header">
        <Hamburger/>
    </header>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Hamburger from "~/components/Hamburger.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    Hamburger
  },
  data() {
    return {
      menuClose: false
    }
  }
}
</script>`

Comment: components/Hamburger.vue `<template>
  <button class="hamburger" v-on:click="$emit('menuClick')">
  </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    menuClick: Boolean
  }
};
</script>`

Comment: Also tried /components/Hamburger.vue `<template>
  <button class="hamburger" v-on:click="$emit('menuClick')">
  </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ["menuClick"],
};
</script>`

Comment: I have added an example, Please check.

Comment: Thanks for this I have spent several hours reading the docs and trying a few things out and had got very close to the same solution but your example is really helpful

Comment: Thank you @rohitpal for a great example. It helped me out.